# VBA code for updating master workbook with data in raw file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to work on a code that would enable me to copy data from the raw file and update the individual sheets in the master workbook for each value in column A of raw file.

Background: There are many unique IDs mentioned in column A of the raw file, other columns contain corresponding data to each unique id. Each unique ID has a separate sheet in the master workbook.

Requirement:

1. Remove unwanted unique ids mentioned in the to be removed sheet in raw file
2. Copy the entire row from the raw file, locate the relevant unique ID sheet in the master workbook and paste the data in the last row.
3. In case the unique id sheet is not there in the master workbook then to create it and paste the data.

Problem:

1. The code that I have gets stuck on locating the correct sheet in the master, it is unable to locate the sheet and when it goes to create a new sheet with the name it gives the error that the sheet name already exists.
2. In case there is a requirement to create a new sheet for a unique id, it should continue looping and paste data for other ids as well.
3. It should give a message box in the end giving details of all new sheets that were created.

Please help me out....I have been trying to solve this for a while now.

Raw file (Excel):
[image: Columns in the raw file excel]

Master File (Excel):
[image: Columns in the master file]

Sheet names in Master File:
[image: Sheet Names in Master File]

Code:

```
    Sub unique_ids()
    Dim NewFN As String, MasterFN As String
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, drow As Long, j as Long
    Dim rngf As Range, rngv As Range
    Dim SName As Variant
    Dim FoundDup As Range

    'Open the Master file
    proceed:
    MasterFN = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All files (*.*), *.*",       Title:="Please open the Master File")
    If MasterFN = "" Then
    MsgBox "You have not selected a file."
    GoTo proceed
    Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MasterFN
    End If
    MasterFN = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'Open the raw file
    proceed1:
    NewFN = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Please open the raw File")
    If NewFN = "" Then
    MsgBox "You have not selected a file."
    GoTo proceed1
    Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=NewFN
    End If

    'Save backup file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Counts-" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks("Counts-" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy") & ".xlsx").Close
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=NewFN
    NewFN = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    'Delete the "to be removed" IDs
    Sheets("counts").Select  
    For Row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 

    Set FoundDup = Sheets("To be deleted").Range("A:A").Find(Cells(Row, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 

    If Not FoundDup Is Nothing Then 
        Cells(Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete 
    End If 

    Next Row

    ‘Update Data

    For j = 2 To lrow
    SName = Workbooks(NewFN).Worksheets("counts").Range("K" & j).Value
    On Error GoTo new_tab
    Workbooks(NewFN).Worksheets("Counts").Range("A" & j & ":I" & j).Copy     Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")
    drow = Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row
    Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & drow - 1 & ":S" & drow - 1).Copy Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & drow & ":S" & drow)
    Next j

    new_tab:
    MsgBox "New ID encountered", vbCritical
   Workbooks(MasterFN).Sheets.Add(after:=Workbooks(MasterFN).Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = SName
    Workbooks(NewFN).Worksheets("counts").Range("A" & j & ":I" & j).Copy       Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")
    drow = Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & drow - 1 & ":S" & drow - 1).Copy  Workbooks(MasterFN).Worksheets(SName).Range("K" & drow & ":S" & drow)

    MsgBox "This work is now complete, new sheet added - " & SName

    End Sub
```

Comment: It may be helpful to edit the question to include a small sample of what the "raw file" looks like. Is it a comma-separated text file, for example? Or does "raw file" mean something else?

Comment: Hey Andrew...I was trying to attach the sample raw and master files but could not figure out how....The data in the raw file are in different columns:A - Unique ID, B - Customer Name, C - I - Data, K - Concatenate formula to add "A" in front of the ID. I thought the issue seems to be that excel is not able to locate numeric sheet names in the master.

Comment: You can't attach files. You need to *show* what they are like. Is your "raw data" an Excel file? Or something else? [Have a look at some database questions for how data is laid out in a `code block` within the question, for example]

Answer (score 0):

The first potential problem I can see here is in the `For j = 2 To lrow` loop you keep referring to the variable `i` instead of what I assume is supposed to be `j`. I can't see that the `i` variable has been initialized anywhere?

Comment: Hey Matt....Thanks for pointing it out, pasted the code from an older version....sorry for that. I have updated the code...however, this does not solve the issue.

Comment: I don't know what the names of your sheets in your raw file are so I can't see where it goes wrong. At what line in the code do you get an error? For the "counts" worksheet you're sometimes writing with upper case C and sometimes lower case, that could be a problem. I would recommend you reference to sheets' [code names](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) instead.

Comment: The raw file contains only two sheets - Counts and To be deleted. The issue is updating data in the master. It is not able to locate the sheet, as a result it moves to the new tab section and creates a new sheet for the unique ID. However since a sheet name with the same Unique ID already exists the code gives me an error at that point. This is the line i get error on -  Workbooks(MasterFN).Sheets.Add(after:=Workbooks(MasterFN).Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = SName. I might be wrong but since I am trying to refer sheet names between two separate workbooks code names would not work here.

Comment: Try changing `SName` from a Variant to a String. That helped me find the sheet when testing. Two lines later it started giving some other problems that I haven't checked, maybe later. Other problems I encountered: `lrow` is never initalized anywhere, and I was unable to enter the `For Row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1` loop until I updated it to `For Row = Sheets("counts").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1`